# Correct usage of words?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

"I took you for a girl with brains"
Is this sentence right?

Technically and scientificically.
Cause humans have only 1brain I presume.

Comment: Should I add any more tags do this?

Comment: What does "technically and scientificically" have to do with it? Check out [Collins, def. 3](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/brains): _(often plural) (informal) intellectual ability ⇒ "he's got brains"_. Oftentimes, informal language is not scientifically or technically correct (as in, _the sky's the limit!_).